# jQuery DataTables with pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have more than 5000 records. Now if I fetch all than my page hang for 10-15 seconds and then show records, I know it is obvious.

Record from where I am fetching is some kind of API. It have facility to fetch record page wise (i.e. record count starting from 20 ) and total number of record (i.e. 10 record or 25 record)

So my idea is that I will show first 10 record than somebody click on paging number  I will bring record another record. But issue how can I show number paging when I am just fetching first 10 records

My Codes

```
function onQuerySuccess() {
 var html = "";

                    while (records.moveNext()) {

                        html += "<tr><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('StaffNo')) + "</td><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('Title')) + "</td><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('JobTitle'));
                        html += "</td><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('Department')) + "</td><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('WorkPhone')) + "</td><td>" + nulltoEmpty(record.get_item('WorkEmail'));
                        html += "</td></tr>";

                        // set lastPageID for last possible item

                    }
                    $('#staff tbody').append(html);
                    $('#staff').DataTable();
                }
```

So how can use iTotalRecords

Comment: You have to use server side script for pagination.  See documentation https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Implement serverside datatable which is very easy and have all the things like pagination, ordering, searching etc. For help check this: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

Comment: Actually why I am not doing server side as I have call API at server side than return record to client so it will be 2 request cycle